# Photos lost in iCloud due to turning off during backup

Tags: icloud, backup, photos

Recently I purchased the .99 cent 50g iCloud backup and attempted to back up my 1000 photos.

Unbeknownst to me my daughter was also logged in under my Apple ID user info. When backup process started I began to see her photos flash thru my photos. Not wanting to have her photos touched I began turning the iCloud backup off and on in a frantic attempt to stop process.

Now not only are my photos gone but also 3000 photos off my daughter’s phone. Needless to say she is VERY upset. I spent four hours on the phone with Apple and they weren’t able to help. There are no photos in my iCloud account and I only have 1 Apple account.

Can anyone help? Has this happened to anyone else where you’ve found a solution to this issue.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I assume the main thing here is to regain access to yours (and your daughter's) photos. Could you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/341530/edit) your question to clarify if you have Photo Stream enabled? If so then your most recent 1,000 photos will be stored there for 30 days. See [My Photo Stream](https://support.apple.com/HT201317) for more info. It's also not clear what backups you may have had? For example, if you have an iPhone were you also backing up via iTunes on a Mac/PC? And did you import any photos to a Mac/PC?

Comment: Monomeeth, unfortunately neither I nor my daughter had iCloud or photo stream on. Also neither had synced with iTunes so there was no backup done. I tried going to iCloud recover sites but all they do is take me to my iCloud where there is nothing stored. It just seems that without intentionally trying to delete photos that they must be somewhere between our phones and the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Apple can surely help you untangle your accounts. As a paying customer they will work with you to explain how to set up two separate accounts, then you can detach from one of the accounts - keep all the combined photos and then sync them to a new account.

Once you have two iCloud accounts you can delete any cross contaminated photos that don’t belong to account A or account B and be happy again.

- http://support.apple.com

This happens all the time when people wanted to share an App Store account for whatever reason and didn’t realize it might share more than you hoped. Hopefully it isn’t all your calendars / contacts / app settings that are mixed as well. That can take a couple hours to a couple days to sort out, but the process is the same. Get everyone their own Apple ID (and only one Apple ID) and then clean up once accounts are individual.